# how to detect the shift-button/clean input in javascript textfield?

Tags: javascript, validation, input, textfield

I have a textfield on which I'm detecting every keypress like this:

```
document.getElementById("postcardText").addEventListener('keyup', checkInput, false);
```

in my checkInput-function I'm checking only for the letters I want users to add. It works fine so far, the problem is that if the user presses the shift-button e.g. shift+A to write a capital A there are 2 keyups detected and A is added twice. 
can anyone suggest a workaround?

EDIT:
this seems to do the job:

```
var shiftKey=false;
$(document).keyup(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 16) {
        //alert("Shift was pressed");
        shiftKey=true;
    } else{
      shiftKey=false;
      checkInput();
    }
});
```

and then in my if-statement something like this

```
function checkInput(){
    if (character=="A" ||
        character=="B" &&
    shiftKey==false){
    //adding letter-image here
    }
}
```

I had to change keydown to keyup, otherwise it doesn't detect the first character immediately, but only when the next key is pressed.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Are you trying to manipulate the content of the text field in some way? Are you going to trigger some other function if the user enters a specific character? Depending on what you're trying to accomplish, maybe you should just read the current data out of the text field on each keyup instead of trying to identify the intent of each of the user's key presses.

Comment: basically this is a "machine" that transforms the input text into a colorful image. so each letter has a image that it is represented by. I want that the user while writing already sees how it looks like.
I am on each keyup reading the data of the textfield and then adding the last letter as an image to my big image. but the shift-button disturbs things... so that's why I'm identifying it...

Comment: if there is an easier way to do this, let me know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comment:

> basically this is a "machine" that transforms the input text into a colorful image. so each letter has a image that it is represented by. I want that the user while writing already sees how it looks like. I am on each keyup reading the data of the textfield and then adding the last letter as an image to my big image. but the shift-button disturbs things...

Would it be too much to rebuild the entire design from scratch every time on keyup? Each time a keyup event is received, wipe away the current image, and loop through each character of the textfield to add its image.

```
$(document).keyup(function (e) {

    // Do whatever you need to do to clear the image… 

    var myText = $("#postcardText").val();
    for (var i = 0; i < myText.length; i++) {

        var thisChar = myText.charAt(i);

        // Add thisChar to the image…
        addLetter(thisChar);
    }
});
```

This method has the added benefit that you can handle arrow keys and even deletions without having to write in exceptions for each of those cases.

Comment: it makes sense but as I see it I need to load all images every time the user types something. Isn't that very ineffective?

Comment: my solution to avoid having to load all letters every time the user types something is adding all possible letters into an invisible div, identifying them by id and copying the source of that image when the user types things. This works perfectly fine! thx!

Answer (score 0):

Are you using jQuery? If yes, you can try to intercept shift key using this:

```
$(document).keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 16) {
        alert("Shift was pressed");
    }
});
```

So you can return `false` or call your function only if the keyCode is different than 16, take a look [here](http://jsfiddle.net/54eDL/)

Comment: a jsFiddle that copies the very simple code posted here, isn't really a valid answer, I think...

Comment: did you try to call your function inside the if (e.keyCode != 16) ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
if (character=="A" || character=="B"){
  if(shiftKey==false){
     //adding letter-image here
  }
}
```

Comment: can you explain why it would work different from 
'if (character=="A" || character=="B" && shiftKey==false)'? It apparently does. I don't know why...

Comment: Can you understand this mathematical logic,  Is there any difference between 10+2*5 and (10+2)*5? The answer should be different.

Comment: so would this be possible? :'if ((character=="A" || character=="B") && shiftKey==false)'

Comment: Yes but i'm not sure, I have tried once in my project but it does not satisfied given condition.